# SAML2 test client

Tags: testing, cas, saml-2.0

I am working on enabling SAMLv2 on an existing CAS server
I've followed the [official procedure](https://wiki.jasig.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063484). Now I'm looking forward testing it.

As I don't have access to the final SP yet, i am looking for a test client that allows me to craft request and see the server's response as XML.

Do you know such a tool?

The closest thing I found is [OpenSAML 2](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual) but it's too low level for my needs...

Thank you.
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [testshib](https://www.testshib.org/) or [OneLogin's SAML Toolkits](https://onelogin.zendesk.com/entries/20186386-introduction-to-onelogin-s-saml-toolkits).

In terms of looking at the XML, see [ADFS : I want to see the SAML data](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/adfs-i-want-to-see-saml-data.html)